# Como funciona el metodo assertQuerysetEqual( response,context['elemento_de_diccionario'] ,['lo que deberia devolver']) DJANGO 2.2.3

Tags: python-3.x, django, test

mi problema es que no me queda claro como funciona el metodo assertQuerysetEqual, estoy haciendo pruebas en mi aplicacion encuestas > test.py , pero me sale un error:
 -> NoneType object is not subscriptable

```
class QuestionIndexViewTest(TestCase):
def test_no_questions(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('encuestas:index'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
    self.assertContains(response,'No hay encuestas que mostrar')
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['lista_de_objects'],[])
def test_past_question(self):
    create_question(question_text='Past question',days=-30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('encuestas:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['lista_de_objects'],['<Question: Past question>']
    )
def test_future_question(self):
    create_question(question_text='future question',days=30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('encuestas:index'))
    self.assertContains(response,'No hay encuestas que mostrar')
    #self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['lista_de_objects'],['<Question: future question>'])
def test_future_question_and_past_question(self):
    create_question(question_text='Past question',days=-30)
    create_question(question_text='Future question',days=30)
    response= self.client.get(reverse('encuestas:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['lista_de_objects'],['<Question: Past question>'])
```

la linea que esta mal es:

> self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['lista_de_objects'],[])

en el metodo test_no_question(self), tenga en cuenta que yo tengo mi models.py ya hecho y con registros ya hechos, pero segun lo que lei si deriva de TestCase la clase crea una base de datos nueva, o eso lei.

en mi views.py la vista index es :

```
def index(request):
last_list_question = Question.objects.filter(date_public__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date_public')[:5]
if last_list_question:
    output = ', '.join([q.question_txt for q in last_list_question])
    #return HttpResponse(output)
    return render(request,'encuestas/index.html',{'lista_de_objects':last_list_question})
else:
    return HttpResponse("No hay encuestas que mostrar")
```

todo los test paso,pero no el error de NoneType, por eso quiero que me digan por favor como funciona ese metodo assertQuerysetEqual()

mi models.py de Question es:

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_txt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date_public  = models.DateTimeField('Fecha de Publicacion')
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.question_txt}'

def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.date_public <= now
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, cualquier duda del codigo haganmelo saber :)

Comment: Te sugiero leer la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual) sobre `assertQuerysetEqual`. La documentación no es muy clara, así que te sugiero también revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610943/django-1-4-assertquerysetequal-how-to-use-method), donde puedes entender mejor como funciona.

Comment: gracias, no importa , aun no lo he resuelto ,perro si lo resuelvo, pondré la respuesta aqui :)

Comment: Si! si logras resolverlo seria genial que publiques tu respuesta, sera de bastante ayuda en la comunidad, ademas de que ni yo tengo claro como funciona :)